# Display data from another table through links in php

Tags: php

I've 2 database table 1 is user table and other is market_offer table. I want to display offers by user. Like when user sends offer only the current offer is been updated rest all offers must be on More offers page and that page should contain only particular user data.

**This is a code:**

```
//Market_offer.php where I have displayed offers according to users_id
<div class="panel panel-body">  
                        <?php 
                        $output = '';  
                        $query =    "SELECT u.*,t.* 
                                    FROM users u
                                    JOIN add_offer t ON t.user_id = u.id
                                    GROUP BY u.id, u.name ORDER BY t.id DESC";  
                        $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))  
                        {  
                            $output .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-6">';  
                            $output .= '<div class="panel panel-default">';  
                            $output .= '<div class="panel-heading">'.preg_replace("/(?!^)./", "*", $row["name"]).'</div>';
                            $output .= '<div class="panel-body">'; 
                            $output .= '<div style="padding:3px;float:left;font-weight:bold;">'.$row["part_no"].'</div>'; 
                            $output .= '<div style="padding:3px;float:left;">'.$row["make"].'</div>'; 
                            $output .= '<div style="padding:3px;float:left;">'.$row["date_code"].'</div>'; 
                            $output .= '<div style="padding:3px;float:left;">'.$row["qty"].'</div>';  
                            $output .= '<br>';  
                            $output .= '<div style="float:left;font-size:9px;">'; 
                            $output .= '<a href="user.php?id='.$row["user_id"].'">More Offers>>';           
                            $output .= '</a>';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '<div style="float:right;font-size:9px;">'.date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($row["time"])).'</div>';
                            $output .= '</div>';  
                            $output .= '</div>';  
                            $output .= '</div>';  
                        }  
                        echo $output;
                        ?>  
                    </div>
//user.php where I want a particular users offers only to be displayed here.
<div class="panel-body" style="padding: 0px;padding-left: 5px;border-bottom: 1px solid #66512c;">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
                            $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
                            $res=mysqli_query( $connect,"SELECT * FROM add_offer WHERE id=$user_id");
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
                                    {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-6">  
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body"> 
                                <div style="padding:3px;float:left;font-weight:bold;">
                                    <?php echo $row["part_no"];?>
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding:3px;float:left;">
                                    <?php echo $row["make"]; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding:3px;float:left;">
                                    <?php echo $row["date_code"]; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding:3px;float:left;">
                                    <?php echo $row["qty"]; ?>
                                </div> 
                                <br>  
                                <div style="float:right;font-size:9px;">
                                    <?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($row["time"])); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                    <?php
                        }
                            }
                    ?>     
                </div>
```